# Refresh LWC (record page) when record is updated

Tags: lightning-web-components, record, refresh

I'm trying to find a way to refresh a custom lwc that's embedded into my record page but I can't find a way to properly achieve this.

I know you can handle this with aura using

```
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
```

But I want to avoid using aura.

Can I really achieve this requirement? Maybe using event listeners?

Regards,

Comment: you can have an aura component without a body with handling event to refresh a page on lightning page and communicate with this aura component from LWC using [LMS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation)

Comment: If you're using a wire service (e.g. getObjectInfo), your component is automatically refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to use [the RefreshView API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/data-refreshview-api.html) now. Import `RefreshView` from `lightning/refresh` and dispatch that event.

```js
import { RefreshEvent } from "lightning/refresh";

export default class YourComponent extends LightningElement {
  method() {
    // this will tell the view to refresh its contents
    this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with **Platform Events** and **Lightning Emp API** .

Link to : [Platform Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_publish_apex.htm)

You create **Platform Event** type for **firing** when a record is updated.
Create **Record Id** field which represents the record which was updated.
In  your trigger you "publish" it :

```java
List<Platform_Event__e> plEvents = new List<Platform_Event__e>();
plEvents.add( new Platform_Event__e (Record_Id__c = myRecord.Id) );
// Call method to publish events
List<Database.SaveResult> results = EventBus.publish(plEvents);
```

Link to : [Lightning Emp API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation) *(for more information)*

Then you **subscribe** to this **Platform Event channel** in your **LWC** with **Lightning Emp API**.

```java
handleSubscribe() {
    // Callback invoked whenever a new event message is received
    const messageCallback = function (response) {
        console.log('New message received: ', JSON.stringify(response));
        // Response contains the payload of the new message received
    };

    // Invoke subscribe method of empApi. Pass reference to messageCallback
    subscribe(this.channelName, -1, messageCallback).then((response) => {
        // Response contains the subscription information on subscribe call
        console.log(
            'Subscription request sent to: ',
                JSON.stringify(response.channel)
        );
        this.subscription = response;
    });
}
```

In your  `messageCallback` method you check if this **Record Id** field equals your `recordId` on the page.
If so you refresh your LWC ( create another method for it I suppose ?).

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using event listeners.
Inside your event listener method use this line it will refresh your Page.

```
eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
```

Comment: This assumes aura, and OP is trying to avoid aura. I also think that the use of `eval()` here is unnecessary and generally bad practice (eval() is evil, as the saying goes).